# Azure Data Factory from VM SQL Server to File on FTP

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-database

This year We moved from hosted servers to Azure VM's, we run two production servers (SQL and IIS). A vital component of our business is bulk transfer of data file.  We take customers data from our SQL Server and then write it out to a file (XLS, CSV, XML, PDF, Word, etc.) and then either email these files to customers or in most cases, push them into their FTP server.  We also have a few import procedures where we retrieve data files.  All of this is currently done with SSIS packages.

We're examining a move to Azure Data Factory as a replacement for SSIS so that we can possibly move to either Azure SQL (if we can work out Broker Services limitations) or an Azure SQL Managed Instance.

I've done some preliminary work with ADF but I saw a couple of posts about lack of FTP support.  Is it possible to create/deliver files to FTP and retrieve/consume files from FTP using ADF?  Also, almost all of these jobs are automated and we use SQL Agent to run the packages.  What is the Azure equivalent for scheduling these jobs to run?

Answer (score 1):

There is automation in ADF but the scheduler is per pipeline. [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/) is more powerful and can automate more than one pipeline (Azure Data Factory v2), if needed.

[Automation with Azure Data Factory (ADF)](https://khangtran.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/automation-with-azure-data-factory-adf/)

You can receive files from FTP into an Azure Data Factory pipeline: [Copy data from FTP server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp) The idea is that you receive a file via FTP to submit to a particular pipeline activity, and that activity pushes data to an Azure data source. It might be possible to reverse the flow, and send data out.

The Azure SQL Database Managed Instance is the most on-premise like database (PaaS) service but SQL Server deployed on an Azure VM still has more functionality.